# Can i use the Crawlable AJAX method without a slash at the start?

Tags: ajax, twitter, hash, seo

Given the two following scenarios, which is good or bad:
1. href="/#!/internal-page"
2. href="#!/internal-page"

Twitter seems to be using the first option, but wouldn't this force a page refresh and thus breaking the seamless ajax experience?
 or do they have another motive for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the showcase page of Google the second option is used. See http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html. If you inspect some of the elements you can see this:

```
<a href="#!CwCheckBox">!CwCheckBox</a>
<a href="#!CwRadioButton">!CwRadioButton</a>
<a href="#!CwBasicButton">!CwBasicButton</a>
```

So the second option should also work :).